# Access to Geospatial Analytics service Dashbord in Bluemix HTTP 404

Tags: geospatial, ibm-cloud

When using the Geopsatial Service in Bluemix, on US South or UK instance I get often HTTP 404 in Bluemix for that service, when trying to open th service . It seems to be depended on Browser and OS:

- Windows 7 Chrome 43.0.2357.124 OK
- Windows 7 FF ESR 31.7 not working
- Ubuntu 14.04 Version 43.0.2357.125 not working
- Ubuntu 14.04 FF 38.0 not working

Does anybody has the same issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for reporting this problem. This is a known issue that will be fixed in an upcoming update to the Geospatial service.  We have noticed that using Chrome has been an effective workaround for most people.

Answer (score 0):

An update was made to the service yesterday that should fix this issue.